# Montreal Canadiens Facebook Graph API returns no posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph

I'm using the Graph API to return Facebook posts from all NHL teams. Every team returns the posts fine except for the Montreal Canadiens, which returns no posts. I verified that there are posts on their wall, and that the Facebook ID that I used is correct(see [here](http://graph.facebook.com/110877132302973))

I get back an empty JSON list when I try using this link for the Canadiens:
https://graph.facebook.com/110877132302973/posts?access_token=(my access token)&limit=10

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Haotian

Answer (score 1):

The posts on that page all have a custom privacy setting - you need to make sure you're attempting to access them using a User access token for a user that meets whatever restrictions they've applied.

App or page access tokens won't be able to see the posts, nor will user tokens for users who don't meet the restrictions